# Can't animate blur and transform together

Tags: css, webkit, css-animations, css-transforms

If I use this code

```
@-webkit-keyframes blurMe{
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  }
}
```

It will work.
But if I add this:

```
0% {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-transform: scale(4,4);
}

100% {
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
}
```

The element I use this keyframes only show scale (from 4 to 2), the blur always be 4px;
that means when getting 100%, `-webkit-filter: blur(0px)` didn't work. Why?
*(using Chrome)*.

Comment: I'm sorry, but '[pictures](http://jsfiddle.net/),' or it didn't happen.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TxWE5/1/ this one~~

Comment: Indeed, problem exists: http://jsfiddle.net/YNLhu/

Comment: P.S.   this bug didn't exist in new chrome

Comment: This works fine in Chrome 45, so I guess this question is irrelevant now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably this is a Chrome bug. But you should realise that when you are three unstable (prefixed) features together, you'll get a result that is unstable^3.

As a workaround you may use two elements and apply different animation to each one:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
.outer,
.inner {
    -webkit-animation: 3s infinite;
}

.outer {
    -webkit-animation-name: scaleMe;
}

.inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-animation-name: blurMe;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blurMe {
    from { -webkit-filter: blur(5px); }
      to { -webkit-filter: blur(0);   }
}

@-webkit-keyframes scaleMe {
    from { -webkit-transform: scale(4); }
      to { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }  
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YNLhu/2/